# Getting XML element based on attribute value

Tags: php, xml, image, parsing

Hey.
 I have an XML file and would like to use `PHP` to display the `medium` size only. The part of the XML looks like this:

```
<image size="small">/small23.png</image>
<image size="medium">/medium23.png</image>
<image size="large">/large23.png</image>
```

I'd like to display the image on the page using `<img src="" />`, but I'm not sure how to put only the medium image. Within a forloop going through all the other elements, I tried this:

```
if($file->image->attributes()->size == "medium")
   echo "<img src=$file->image />";
```

but nothing is drawn.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your example I assume you're using SimpleXML, so try this:

```
$mediums = $file->xpath("image[@size='medium']");
if (count($mediums)) {
    echo '<img src="' . (string) $mediums[0] . '" />';
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Hadn't looked at the xpath method before.

Answer (score 2):

```
$done = false;
foreach($file->image as $img) {
    foreach($img->attributes() as $key => $value) {
        if($key == "size" && $value == "medium") {
            echo "<img src = {$file->image} />";
            $done = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if($done) { break; }
}
```

This might work, try it out and let me know.

Comment: doing two foreach loops when you just want to find one known attribute from one specific element is complete overkill